# read couple of xml file and saved them as list of list

Tags: python-3.x, xml, list

I have a 112 XML file, each contains a  paragraph, like this: (this is one XML sample, we have 112 samples)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<arggraph id="micro_b001" topic_id="waste_separation" stance="pro">
  <edu id="e1"><![CDATA[Yes, it's annoying and cumbersome to separate your rubbish properly all the time.]]></edu>
  <edu id="e2"><![CDATA[Three different bin bags stink away in the kitchen and have to be sorted into different wheelie bins.]]></edu>
  <edu id="e3"><![CDATA[But still Germany produces way too much rubbish]]></edu>
  <edu id="e4"><![CDATA[and too many resources are lost when what actually should be separated and recycled is burnt.]]></edu>
  <edu id="e5"><![CDATA[We Berliners should take the chance and become pioneers in waste separation!]]></edu>
  <adu id="a1" type="opp"/>
  <adu id="a2" type="opp"/>
  <adu id="a3" type="pro"/>
  <adu id="a4" type="pro"/>
  <adu id="a5" type="pro"/>
  <edge id="c6" src="e1" trg="a1" type="seg"/>
  <edge id="c7" src="e2" trg="a2" type="seg"/>
  <edge id="c8" src="e3" trg="a3" type="seg"/>
  <edge id="c9" src="e4" trg="a4" type="seg"/>
  <edge id="c10" src="e5" trg="a5" type="seg"/>
  <edge id="c1" src="a1" trg="a5" type="reb"/>
  <edge id="c2" src="a2" trg="a1" type="sup"/>
  <edge id="c3" src="a3" trg="c1" type="und"/>
  <edge id="c4" src="a4" trg="c3" type="add"/>
</arggraph>
```

I want to read each of them in python and gather from each of the text that ends with "edu" ,and then saved them as

list of the list! like this

```
[[Yes, it's annoying and cumbersome to separate your rubbish properly all the time., Three different bin bags stink away in the kitchen and have to be sorted into different wheelie bins., But still Germany produces way too much rubbish
  ,and too many resources are lost when what actually should be separated and recycled is burnt , We Berliners should take the chance and become pioneers in waste separation!] , [

next XML content] ,[next, XML content],...
]]
```

I have tried this way

I have saved them all of them as list in myList

```
myList = []  
myEdgesList=[]
#read the whole text from 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), encoding="UTF-8") as content:
                tree = ET.parse(content)
                myList.append(tree)
```

then:

```
ParaList=[]
EduList=[]
for k in myList:
    a=k.findall('.//edu')
    for l in a:
        EduList.append(l.text)
ParaList.append(EduList)
```

but the result only gives me a flat list of all sentences (576) and not a list of 112 paragraphs

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `myList` is a list of parsed XML documents, moving `ParaList.append(EduList)` inside the main for loop should fix it for you. You also need to reset the `EduList` once per document, so also move `EduList=[]` inside the main loop:

```
ParaList=[]
for k in myList:
    EduList=[]
    a=k.findall('.//edu')
    for l in a:
        EduList.append(l.text)
    ParaList.append(EduList)
```

Now the extracted content of each XML document is appended to `ParaList` once per document.

A better way to write this code is to use a list comprehension to process the matching lines:

```
ParaList=[]
for k in myList:
    ParaList.append([l.text for l in k.findall('.//edu')])
```

Or you could even do it in one line using a nested list comprehension:

```
ParaList = [[l.text for l in k.findall('.//edu')] for k in myList]
```

Comment: it works man!  it is 2:00 AM  in Germany, I really made a childish mistake,  I actually only  forgot to reset Edulist, (Parlist move, has been tried) thank you for other elegant ways also

Comment: @DevAM: you are welcome. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I want to extract from these XML files , paragraphs.  and then put  each Paragraph as one row of the data frame, can you help me also in this regard?

Comment: I tried to vote...but my account has not such a reputation to do it...sorry

Comment: Possibly `pd.DataFrame(['\n'.join([l.text for l in k.findall('.//edu')]) for k in myList], columns=['Paragraph'])` could work.

Comment: Or, since you already have `ParaList`, `pd.DataFrame(['\n'.join(paragraph) for paragraph in ParaList], columns=['Paragraph'])`

Comment: @DevAM: I think that you can still accept. No big deal.

Comment: @DevAM: no worries... have you been to bed?

Comment: yes! I waked up now ...still need to work!

Comment: the things, I want to have a data frame with 112 rows, in each row should be text as a list of sentences,,not as joint...

Comment: OK, then take out the `join()`: `pd.DataFrame([paragraph for paragraph in ParaList], columns=['Paragraph'])`

Comment: i tried that before, it does not work, says ```1 column passed, passed data had 10 columns```

Comment: How about `pd.DataFrame([[paragraph] for paragraph in ParaList], columns=['Paragraph'])`?